# COUNTIFS formula to refer to a dynamic range in another sheet from the active sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I am trying to incorporate this COUNTIFS formula into a worksheet via VBA but cannot seem to get it to work and with my rather limited VBA skills I've hit a bit of a brick wall.

This is the formula I want to incorporate but I want the range to be dynamic rather than fixed:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Scheme Information'!$B$5:$B$20000,COMPILED!$A2,'Scheme Information'!$A$5:$A$20000,COMPILED!H$1)>0,"Yes","")
```

The VBA code I have written always errors at the .Range stage.

```
Sub COUNTIFS_Formula()

    Dim SourceLastRow As Long
    Dim OutputLastRow As Long
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet

    'Name sheets for reference
    Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Scheme Information")  ' SOURCE
    Set outputSheet = Worksheets("COMPILED")            ' OUTPUT

    'Determine last row of Scheme Information sheet
    With sourceSheet
        SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Add in formula
    With outputSheet
        OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("H2:H" & OutputLastRow).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS('" & sourceSheet.Name & "!$B$2:$B$" & SourceLastRow & "," _
            & outputSheet.Name & "$A2," & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$B$2:$B$" & SourceLastRow & "," & outputSheet.Name & "!H$1)>0" & "," & ""YES"" & "," & "")"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The `&` should be on the top row `& _` and removed from the second.

Comment: you are also missing a `!` on `outputSheet.Name & "$A2`

Comment: and `>0" & "," & ""YES"" & "," & "")"` should be `>0,""YES"","""")"`

Comment: Thank you so much - I have made the changes you suggested and I no longer get an error, however, the formula returns as #VALUE!s - this is the resulting formula: =IF(COUNTIFS('Scheme Information!$B$2:[$B$17718,COMPILED!$A2,Scheme Information]$B$17718,COMPILED!$A2,Scheme In'!$B$2:$B$17718,COMPILED!H$1)>0,"YES","")

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to solve a problem if you break it down into smaller parts.

> .Range("H2:H" & OutputLastRow).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS('" & sourceSheet.Name & "!$B$2:$B$" & SourceLastRow & "," _
> & outputSheet.Name & "$A2," & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$B$2:$B$" & SourceLastRow & "," & outputSheet.Name & "!H$1)>0" & "," & ""YES"" & "," & "")"

At the very least you should assign the formula to a string variable before you assign it to the `Range.Formula`.  This makes it easy to print the result out to the Immediate Window for inspection.

```
Sub COUNTIFS_Formula()
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim SourceFormula As String
    With wsSchemeInformation
        Set Source = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 1)
        SourceFormula = FormulaAddress(Source)
    End With

    Dim OutputFormula As String, OutputA2Formula As String, OutputH2Formula As String
    Dim Output As Range
    With wsCompiled
        Set Output = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 1)
        
        OutputFormula = FormulaAddress(Output)
        OutputA2Formula = FormulaAddress(.Range("A2"))
        OutputH2Formula = FormulaAddress(.Range("H2"))
    End With
    
    Dim FormulaRange As Range
    Set FormulaRange = Output.EntireRow.Columns("H")
    
    Dim FormulaParts As Variant
    FormulaParts = Array("=IF(COUNTIFS(", SourceFormula, ",", OutputA2Formula, ",", SourceFormula, ",", OutputH2Formula, ")>0", ",", """YES""", ")")
    
    Dim Formula As String
    Formula = Join(FormulaParts, "")
    FormulaRange.Formula = Formula

End Sub

Function FormulaAddress(Target As Range)
    FormulaAddress = "'" & Target.Parent.Name & "'!" & Target.Address
End Function

Function wsCompiled() As Worksheet ' OUTPUT
    Set wsCompiled = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("COMPILED")
End Function

Function wsSchemeInformation() As Worksheet ' SOURCE
    Set wsSchemeInformation = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scheme Information")
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you TinMan - this is great. I did consider breaking it down into smaller parts but as the COUNTIFS need to check 19 different headings, from H1 through to Z1, I thought I'd be able to simply repeat the formula, accordingly tweaking the code incrementally each time. Is it all possible to adapt your code to perform this? I appreciate that wasn't mentioned in my original post but it was my intention to get that one formula working and then apply it to the other 19 headers.

Comment: @TheEndUK II don't know the problem well enough to say what's the best approach.  It my be as simple as adjusting range anchors ($, the relative and absolute references).

Comment: Thanks TinMan - here is the VBA I have been using but I want to make the range it's referring to in the TPR sheet dynamic:      With Sheets("COMPILED")
        .Range("H2:AA" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIFS(TPR!R5C2:R20000C2,COMPILED!RC1,TPR!R5C1:R20000C1,COMPILED!R1C)>0,""Yes"","""")"
     End With

Comment: @TheEndUK You should post this as a different question.  It is hard to answer in a comment.  Providing a mock workbook download link would also help.  Read [R1C1-Style Notation And The FormulaR1C1 Property In Excel VBA: Tutorial And Examples](https://powerspreadsheets.com/r1c1-formular1c1-vba/).  Dynamic rows:

Comment: With Sheets("COMPILED")
        With .Range("H2:AA" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIFS(TPR!R5C2:R" & .Row & "C2,COMPILED!RC1,TPR!R5C1:R2" & .Row & "C1,COMPILED!R1C)>0,""Yes"","""")"
        End With
    End With

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice, TinMan - I will do as suggested and start a new post. Regards, TE